# Found an exploit to my website, how was it used against me?

Tags: php, security, exploit

A month or so ago my website was hacked. My host doesnt keep very good logs, so I don't know what specifically was accessed. The hacker claimed in our IRC that he used some kind of RCE (remote code execution) but refused to elaborate. Whatever he did, he uploaded an obfuscated php script to the site and assumed control of the database where he then made himself an admin user on the site.

The framework I use is called kusaba, version 0.9.3.  The previous versions have had several reported exploits, which were patched in this release.

Well, one site, written in Spanish, talked of an exploit (below), but I can't make it work unless I am doing it w

```
https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fvammm.wordpress.com%2F2012%2F09%2F07%2Fkusaba-x-0-9-3-0day-xss%2F&edit-text=&act=url
```

I posted the given code into an html doc, inside script tags, and accessed the page online. Nothing. Tried accessing the direct link, below, which also does nothing.

> http://postherwin.com/threadwatch.php?o=addthread&board=\%27%29%3B%22%3E%3C%2Fa%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%28document.cookie%29%3B%2F*a*%2F%3C%2Fscript%3E%3C!--

Given the parameters above, how was he able to upload the shell? How can I prevent it?

Comment: It looks like an XSS where someone harvested the `document.cookie` for users using that URL (with the session ID), which was then used to impersonate that user (session fixation) and apparently gain access to your system (including filesystem).

Comment: Im not sure how that works, would they have needed access to my desktop, or is that something they can do remotely?

Comment: If they had access to your desktop you'd know it because your desktop background would have been changed to a lot of dongs.

Comment: You should read on it, if you want to understand it. [This series](http://coffeeonthekeyboard.com/best-basic-security-practices-especially-with-django-697/) is good about the concepts (although it deals in Django). And no, it doesn't have anything to do with your desktop (I'm 99.9% certain).

Comment: Looks like kusaba is pretty vulnerable - https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl#q=kusaba+vulnerability

Comment: My desktop didnt seem affected, but I did a fresh windows install anyway. Raidanace, I knew it was vulnerable, I was just hoping that the latest version would have been more sanitized.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it wasn't the unrecorded `threadwatch.php` vulnerability that you mentioned in your question, the attacker could have used the following exploit. [CVE-2008-5663](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2008-5663):

> Multiple unrestricted file upload vulnerabilities in Kusaba 1.0.4 and earlier allow remote authenticated users to execute arbitrary code by uploading a file with an executable extension using (1) load_receiver.php or (2) a shipainter action to paint_save.php, then accessing the uploaded file via a direct request to this file in their user directory.

### [Kusaba 'paint_save.php' Remote Code Execution Vulnerability](http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/31668)

> Kusaba 'paint_save.php' Remote Code Execution Vulnerability
>
> Kusaba is prone to a remote code-execution vulnerability because the application fails to properly sanitize user-supplied input.
>
> Exploiting this issue allows attackers to cause the application to execute arbitrary code within the context of the webserver.
>
> Kusaba 1.0.4 is vulnerable; other versions may also be affected.

### [Kusaba 'load_receiver.php' Remote Code Execution Vulnerability](http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/31685)

> Kusaba 'load_receiver.php' Remote Code Execution Vulnerability
>
> Kusaba is prone to a remote code-execution vulnerability because the application fails to properly sanitize user-supplied input.
>
> Exploiting this issue allows attackers to cause the application to execute arbitrary code within the context of the webserver.
>
> Kusaba 1.0.4 is vulnerable; other versions may also be affected.

The solution is the same in both cases:

> The vendor released fixes to address this issue. Please see the references for more information.

So my recommendation is to use a version of Kusaba later than 1.0.4.

The `threadwatch.php` vulnerability appears to be another sanitization problem. The framework fails to correctly sanitize or output encode the data stored into the database. This means that when a valid user then accesses the system, an [XSS attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) can happen (e.g. sending your cookies to the attacker or installing a keylogger into the website for your session).

It is not clear from the details regarding the `threadwatch.php` vulnerability how Remote Code Execution was achieved, but since there are other ways the attacker could have achieved this as I have detailed above it is a moot point - you should upgrade to a fixed version of the framework.

Answer (score 0):

From the sound of it, you've been locally hacked. My advice, change all passwords, you need to have a password with 1 or more capital letters, 1-2 numerical letters, and 1-2 special characters such as 1-0 with the shift button. !@#$%^&*()_+. That right there is the best security you can buy. Otherwise, you're left open to be used. Many pre-made scripts have very visible errors. There many security measures that could've been made. Honestly, learn how to code. 99% of questions asked are over-shown. Brute force may work some of the time, but you're forced to wait when it comes to smart Americans.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I can code in Java, Python, and basic C++/C#, but I don't have any classes for PHP until next year.

Comment: When using commercial applications the security goes down. Essentially, less you spend the better you get. Ask any installer, they can get you free HBO but dunno how or why.